# I need to close a Vimeo video after it is done playing

Tags: onload, vimeo

I'm using vimeo to display a video that autoplays on the site load.

I'm looking for a way to both close the video and the containing div after the video is done playing.

Can anyone help me out with this?

The site can be viewed here: http://www.farrago-studio.com/

Thanks in advance